Transition probability from state $i$ to state $j$, $j=i\pm1$ in a process with an $\infty$ queue and $n$ operators
From what I understood:

if we have $j1$ received requests, then we have a factor $\frac{(\lambda h)^{j1}}{j1!}e^{-\lambda h}$.
if we have $j2$ processed requests, then we have a factor $(P({\tau<t}))^{j2}=(1-e^{-\mu h})^{j2}$, if $j2$ unprocessed requests, then: $P({\tau>t})^{j2}=(1-P({\tau<t}))^{j2}=(1-(1-e^{-\mu h}))^{j2}=(e^{-\mu h}))^{j2}$.
Transition probability formula: $Lij(t)=lim_{h->+0}\frac{P({x_{t}=i;x_{t+h}=j})}{h}$

How can we now understand what $j1$, $j2$ are for $Lpq$?
The system transitions from state $p$ to state $q$ - this means that: $k1+r1$ were serviced and $r1$ new requests were received, if $p1-q1=k1$; $k2+r2$ new requests were received, $r2$ requests were serviced, if $q2-p2=k2$. How does the presence or absence of a queue and the number of operators affect this?
Chain for the death-reproduction process. The queue is $\infty$, the number of operators is $n$. The arrow indicates the state from which the queue begins.

